# Avoid all layouts being combined into one page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am trying to move over my bootstrap file on html to being implemented with meteor. I want everything to be on seperate pages, but my program is showing all my pages on one page even though I am routing the files via angular-ui-router. This is my routes.js file which I placed in the root/client folder:

```
angular.module("project").config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
      .state('aboutus', {
      url: '/aboutus',
      templateUrl: 'client/views/about.html',
      })
      .state('contactus',{
          url: '/contactus', 
          templateUrl: 'client/views/contact.html',
      })
      .state('home', {
          url: '/home', 
          templateUrl: 'client/views/index.html',
      })
      .state('services', {
        url: '/services',
        templateUrl: 'client/views/services.html',
      })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
  }]);
```

If you want to see the whole project, here it is:
https://github.com/Aggr0vatE/project

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Im trying to make it so that there are multiple routes not everything being shown on one page

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp):

> Meteor scans all the HTML files in your directory for three top-level elements: `<head>`, `<body>`, and `<template>`. The head and body sections are separately concatenated into a single head and body, which are transmitted to the client on initial page load.

You need to structure your html files to take advantage of Meteor templates. The fact that you have everything in `head` and `body` tags is why it's being concatenated together into one page. I'd suggest reading some of the docs in the above link.

Comment: So I took out all the body and head tags from my 4 html files but now i get an error message saying that i have bad formatting for my html template.

Comment: Did you take out the actual tags? Or the tags and the content that they held? Again.. I suggest reading the docs about Meteor templates

Comment: Yes i took out the actual tags. I did this because other meteor projects didn't seem to have any of the tags at all.

Comment: Then its not valid html. You need to have your content in either a `<head>`, `<body>`, or `<template>` tag in Meteor

Comment: then how am supposed to make them separate without meteor concatenating it into a single file?

Comment: The templates portion of the meteor tutorial gives a good overview of how to structure your html files: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates